# Togglz application context listener warning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, togglz

I've implemented a basic `togglz` setup using Spring Boot starter. I'm getting the following at startup:

> WARN  o.t.s.l.TogglzApplicationContextBinderApplicationListener - ApplicationContext already bound to current context class loader, releasing it first

This may also be causing multiple startups, as I sometimes see the Spring banner go by twice.

To summarize my implementation:

- Using property-based toggles in `application.yml`
- Wiring `FeatureManager` into components
- Have a configuration which returns a `SpringSecurityUserProvider` bean
- Not using a `TogglzConfig` (though I tested with it, and see no difference)

I've looked at the `Togglz` class, and see the log warning, but I don't understand what situation in Spring Boot would cause this error.

Thank you!